# Logging data with scribe

Tags: logging, scribe-server

None of the scribe examples I've seen actually mention the best way to take logs/logfiles and send them to scribe.  I could configure a logrotate script that has a postrotate section that "cats" the rotated file to scribe (but then I get minutes latency at best).
The other option is to keep a "tail -f= | my_scribe_sender" and hope that the process never gets killed.  However then you really can't guarantee that you're not missing/duplicating data.

Answer (score 1):

These two links might be helpful:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/scribeserver/forums/forum/870823/topic/2551690

http://www.silassewell.com/blog/2009/05/12/pipe-apache-or-any-logs-to-scribe/

Answer (score 1):

Answer given by Epcylon can be only used for 'cating' files, if you want per message logging this link can be useful: [scribe and php](http://www.ruturaj.net/scribe-php-logging), I don't know what language you use, so google them. There is a thrift interface that can be used with many languages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP, here is a guide to making logging calls to a Scribe server: http://www.alphadevx.com/a/85-Logging-Messages-to-Scribe-from-PHP